# How to enable / disable the zoom button (green + button)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, button, zooming, nswindow

I'm new in Mac OSx / Cocoa development. During the creation of my first app, I bumped into a few things, and one of which is my issue on the green + button which is intended for zooming purposes.

I'd like to know if it is possible to dynamically set the behavior of the zoom button of the app window? Am I not violating any rule from Apple's guidelines?

I want to specify the behavior of the button according to a specific user. Say, the user is allowed to have a zooming button, then the button should be enabled; otherwise, leave the button disabled.

In this case, when the app is launched, I am checking if the user is allowed to have an enabled zoom button. From here I want to customize the behavior of the window pertaining to the zoom button - whether it should be enabled or disabled according to the prior checking of the user's mode.

Thanks ahead for the help!

Comment: Why would zooming ever be restricted?  Its actions would be based on the content's windowing size, which is *not* secret information, since the scrollbars need it too.  The user could get around restriction by sizing the window themselves.  The window's size is a user-side terminal attribute, not something that should be controlled by the server end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get a reference to that button with `standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton`, and then do whatever you can do with any `NSButton`.

**Update** (in swift):

```
var button = view.window?.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)
button?.enabled = false
```

Comment: See Sam Soffes' answer below for the correct way to do this.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to keep your window resizable, but don't want your application to fill the whole screen on button press, this code disables the green zoom button.

Answer (score 7):

Grabbing the button and setting enabled is not ideal. The best way (10.6+) is to use `setStyleMask:`. Here's how to do this:

```
window.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
```

You can add or remove styles at will. Another way to do this without changing the style is to set `minSize` and `maxSize` to the same size. This will also disable resizing.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, here is the easiest way to remove the ability:

```
var style = window.styleMask
style.remove(.resizable)
window.styleMask = style
```

I commonly do this in `viewDidAppear` for view controllers in storyboards that have a window controller created for them automatically instead of one I can mess with.